# No sound on huawei D14 laptop with intel 11th Gen kernel 6.2.0-36-generic

Tags: audio, intel, huawei

This if my output from lspci:

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)

aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no se encontraron tarjetas de sonido...

[image]

my dmesh log:

```
[    4.611078] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    4.611137] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.611353] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: overriding default IPC 0 to requested 1
[    4.611360] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.611453] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.618118] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    4.652070] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: NHLT_DEVICE_I2S detected, ssp_mask 0x1
[    4.652075] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Overriding topology with MCLK mask 0x1 from NHLT
[    4.652086] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[    4.653363] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Loaded firmware library: ADSPFW, version: 2.5.0.1
[    4.766508] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Booted firmware version: 2.5.0.1
[    4.769952] kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk mask 0x20
[    4.769956] kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk SSP0
[    4.769957] kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk DMIC enabled
[    4.770270] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Direct firmware load for intel/avs-tplg/sof-tgl-es8336-dmic2ch-ssp0.tplg failed with error -2
[    4.770272] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: tplg request firmware intel/avs-tplg/sof-tgl-es8336-dmic2ch-ssp0.tplg failed err: -2
[    4.770275] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: you may need to download the firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
[    4.770276] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP topology -2
[    4.770277] kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_probe on 0000:00:1f.3: -2
[    4.770283] kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: failed to instantiate card -2
[    4.770315] kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: snd_soc_register_card failed: -2
[    4.770316] kernel: sof-essx8336: probe of sof-essx8336 failed with error -2
```

Comment: You're missing firmware files. Please install the sof-firmware package or whatever it's called in your distro or download the files from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/